# Internal Server Error occurs with PHP

Tags: php

http://tvreaderservice.info/forms/xlSheet2.php

http://tvreaderservice.info/forms/xlSheet2.html

Both are same page only the extension is different
Internal Server Error is occurring on trying with php what is the problem can you help me?
i just create same html page for testing 
But the html page show all the values
i need to run the page as php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look into your `.htaccess` file. A misconfiguration in that file leads to such errors.

1. Give a dump of your `.htaccess` file here and we may help you.
2. Show us the error logs of your server.

**[EDIT]: After OP posting Error Logs**:

1. Your `.htaccess` is fine.
2. There are many errors in your Error Log. Following are recurring and prominent:

   - PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library "openssl.so"
   - PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library "mysqli.so"
   - WordPress database error Unknown column 'link_category' in 'field list' for query INSERT INTO wp_links.
   - WordPress database error Duplicate entry '8-2' for key 1 for query INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships.
   - **and** many more Wordpress errors.

So, contact your webhost and ask them to fix PHP startUp Errors and fix Wordpress errors yourself (or upgrade to a new version.)

Comment: Now, please remove tvreaderservice.info/error.html and tvreaderservice.info/htcs.html files from server as they pose security risk.